# Default Filter on Power View Report inside Silverlight webpart

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, powerview

Is it possible to provide default filtration criteria for Power View Reports in SharePoint 2013 Silver light web part?

URL Inside Silverlight web part is as follows?

```
"ItemPath=http://mySharePoint/Report.rdlx,ReportServerUri=http://mySharePoint/_vti_bin/ReportServer,ViewMode=Presentation,PreviewBar=False,Fit=True"
```

I would like to filter Report.rdlx with predefined Month-Year for which I have DimDate Dimension table in the report.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 Sp1 Cu4 (on your SharePoint servers that are running SSRS in integrated mode) Power View supports [applying filters via report URL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rhysschmidtke/archive/2013/12/09/add-power-view-filters-to-a-report-url.aspx). You might have to change the format of your report url to make it work (see the comments on that link).

Here's an example:

```
http://mySharePoint/_layouts/15/ReportServer/AdHocReportDesigner.aspx?RelativeReportUrl=[MyReportPath.rdlx]&rf=[DimDate].[MonthYear] eq 'Jan 2013'
```